# Square root without a calculator algorithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, radicals

Out of curiosity I'm trying to find an effective algorithm to find the value of a square root of a number(a) without a calculator. I'm trying to find a solution without searching it up. 
What I have so far:
$$
\sqrt{a} = a^{1/2}
$$
$$
a^2 = a.a
$$
$$
a^3 = a.a.a
$$
$$
a^n = a x .\cdots .n
$$
All I need to know is what will $a^{1/2}$ equal to?

I tried:
$$
a^{1/2} = a . \frac{a}{2}
$$
$$
a^{1/2} =  (a.a)/a
$$

But these are definitely wrong

Comment: If I was trying to compute by hand a square root, I'd either use some form o Taylor Series if a perfect square was nearby,or I"d use the [Babylonian Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)

Comment: "But none of them work" Well, they are obviously wrong.

Comment: Of course they are wrong, I just wanted to show what I've tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Newton_Raphson Method
$$x=\sqrt{a}\rightarrow x^2-a=0$$
or
$$y=x^2-a$$
$$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{y}{y'}$$
$$x_{i+1}=x_i-\frac{x_i^2-a}{2x_i}=\frac{x_i^2+a}{2x_i}$$

Comment: we were shown this in school. I may have been the only student who worked out examples at length. As the division steps are done by hand, I asked how many decimal places to carry the division at any given step. I don't recall how it came out...

Answer (score 4):

If you start with a somewhat good guess $y$ for$\sqrt a$, then $\frac{y+\frac ay}2$ will be a significantly better guess ...

Answer (score 0):

you can see that $x=\sqrt{a}$ is a solution of $x^2-a=0$, so you could apply the [bissection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) on the function $f(x) = x^2-a$, like

$a = 2\\
a_1 = 1, a_2 = 4\\
f(a_1)=1^2-2=-1\\
f(a_2)=4^2-2=16-2=14\\
x = \frac{a_1 + a_2}{2}=\frac{1+4}{2}=2.5\\
f(\frac{5}{2})=4.25\\
a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2,5\\
...$

so you repeat a similiar process acording the precision you wanting to get

Answer (score 0):

Via the Babylonian method mentioned by Mefitico (input your initial guess as $1$ or $x$ for this):

$$\sqrt x =\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggr[\frac{\sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-1}}{\binom{2^n}{2r}x^r}}{\sum_{r=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}{\binom{2^n}{2r+1}x^r}}\biggr]$$

Answer (score 0):

A square root can be quickly converted to small square roots:

Square Root of C = Square Root (C / (2^n)) * Square Root (2^(n-1) * 2)

with C >= 2^n and C < 2^(n+1) .

Also, Square Root (2^even_number) = 2^(even_number / 2) .